# android - using pending intent to start activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 apps App1 and App2. I need to test sending a pending intent from App1 to App2 that allows App2 to start an activity in App1.

In App1 (Main Activity):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.testapp1.app", "Activity2");
PendingIntent pit = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, i, 0);
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.testapp2.app.activity2_action");
intent.putExtra("pi", pit);

startActivity(intent);
```

In App2's Activity2 :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
PendingIntent pi = i.getParcelableExtra("pi");
pi.send();
```

This doesn't launch App1's Activity2. What am I missing in this use of pending intent ? Am I using pending intent the wrong way ?

Comment: Does it do something? Throw an exception? Or just nothing?

Comment: It doesn't do anything :(

Comment: @matiash do you know the problem ?

Comment: not really, sorry. just trying to deduce a possible cause :/

Comment: @matiash do you think the code makes sense ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `intent.setAction("com.android.testapp2.app.activity2_action");` line. Is the problem that the second app isn't launching from the first? Or rather that the second app launches, but `pi.send()` does nothing?

Comment: Second app launches, but pi.send() does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56052/discussion-between-matiash-and-jake).