# Pending Intent to start an Activity on top of another one

Tags: android, android-intent

**Context / my app:**

I'm working on an app that shows image previews on behalf of another app (any app, but let's use a Shopping app as an example). A typical user session would look like (in terms of activities that stack on each other):

1. Shopping: main screen
2. Shopping: item detail screen
3. Previews: display one image in full screen, allow navigation to other images

... then where things get a little tricky, when in Previews: user activates menu "share as"

4. *Shopping*: handles the action "share as" with a floating dialog

Step (4) needs to be handled by Shopping because there's some Shopping-specific logic in there about how to handle this, but it's part of the same task (actually, as a dialog on top of it).

One way to do this is that Previews would get from Shopping an Intent to handle the "share as" action on a give item, so in Previews:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) {
  if (action == shareAs) {
    startActivity(shareAsIntent);
  }
  ...
}
```

and the shareAsIntent points to an exposed activity in Shopping that displays as a Dialog, everything is fine.

**But**

... we want that activity to be private and the intent be explicit, for security reasons (Shopping is happy that Previews gets to call that method, but not any other app on the phone).

**PendingIntent to the rescue?**

One useful candidate in solving this might be using a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). They're typically used for granting another app the permissions to execute a private Activity, great! The issue is, executing the pending intent (.send()) will launch a new task, and the (step 4: Dialog) does not appear on top of (step 3: Display image), as it used to when I was using a simple Intent.

I've read articles about [preserving navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html), and other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346423/android-using-pending-intent-to-start-activity) about pending intents, but they mostly refer to what pending intents seem to be made for: restarting an activity from another app's service, and so the whole task stack belongs to the application that creates the pending intent, not the one that uses it.

**Summary**

Precisely my question is: how can I put the activity that is launched by a pending intent on top of the task of the activity (of app B - Previews) that executes it, rather than the one that created it (app A - Shopping), the exact same way as if I had called (from app B): startActivity(intent)?